# AJAX Pages - How to use #home etc

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make AJAX pages using the [post from Tutorialzine](http://tutorialzine.com/2009/09/simple-ajax-website-jquery/).

This script makes pages appear using AJAX. The problem is that the script works with numbers, example: `http://example.com/#page1`, `http://example.com/#page2` etc..

How to make this script so it doesn't need the `#page1` or `#page2` in the URL, but `#home` etc..

Sorry if I explained this wrong, English isn't my native language and it's hard for me to explain.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#page4">Page 4</a></li>
<li><img id="loading" src="img/ajax_load.gif" alt="loading" /></li>
</ul>

<div id="pageContent"></div>
```

---

**script.js**

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

---

**load_page.php**

```
<?php

if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to do 4 small changes

1) instead `url=url.replace('#page','');`  use `url=url.replace('#','');` so the output in case of `#page1` will be `page1` or `#home` -> `home` pas that `url` to ajax in same way as it now and make ajax to your `load_page.php`

2) rename all your `page_1.html` html files to `pages/page_home.html`

3) change your `<a href="#page1">Page 1</a>` links to `<a href="#home">Page 1</a>`

4) change `$page = (int)$_POST['page'];` in `load_page.php` to `$page = $_POST['page'];`

so it mean according to your hash `#some_name` you should have `page_some_name.html`

Comment: I can't get it to work, am I doing something wrong maybe? Tried all your steps but it says "there is no such page".

Comment: add in `load_page.php` `var_dump($_POST['page'])` and see what is inside if it correct, and make sure you have `pages/page_DUMPED_VALUE.html` file

Comment: gives me "string(4) "home" There is no such page!", I have page_home.html inside pages/

Comment: And have you renamed `pages/page_1.html` to `pages/page_home.html` ? are you sure that you have `pages/page_home.html` file ?

Comment: If you have it then `var_dump( 'pages/page_'.$page.'.html' )` see what it gives you, and check if `PATH` is correct to your htmls `PATH/pages/page_home.html` file, `file_exists()` can't work wrong ...

Comment: I'll give up, haha. It gives me this `Notice: Undefined variable: page in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\load_page.php on line 5
string(16) "pages/page_.html" There is no such page!`, surely I'm not understanding the code

Comment: Aha now i see the last problem you have in `load_page.php` `$page = (int)$_POST['page'];` it it converts `home` to integer just comment that line so you will have in `$page` home value

Comment: sorry i mean not comment but change to `$page = $_POST['page'];`

Comment: ITS WORKS! Thank you so much. Helps alot! Thanks.